# Javascript - Plugin for simulating HTML5 local storage

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, local-storage

I have a page in which I upload an image and then get it in JS for client-side cropping with Crop.js

I get the image like this :

```
$('#uploadButton').on('change', function(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();
     evt.stopPropagation();
     handleFile(evt.target.files[0], 'profilPic');
});
```

Then my handleFile() function uses crop.js on it. Works perfectly in all browsers except Internet Explorer which doesn't support html5 file API before his version 10.

I was using a Flash plugin to reproduce the same behavior on IE but for some reason it is slow, buggy, and sometimes makes IE crash (maybe the reason is that it's Flash).

Is there any way (JS would be the best, in my opinion) to have a way of storing the image locally in IE in the same way that `evt.target.files[0]` does ?

Comment: I think you might be confusing _HTML5 Local Storage_ with the _HTML5 File API_ – I can’t see the former having anything to do with this.

Comment: IE supports storage [from version 8 onwards](http://caniuse.com/#search=storage), you mean something else?

Comment: My bad. I was talking about the HTML5 File API, not local storage. Edited

Comment: If you want to manipulate/read a dropped/selected file client-side using javascript and nothing else, you must use a browser that supports the File API.  There isn't any sort of polyfill that will be able to help you here.